# OnClick and OnKeyPress for standards compliance

Tags: javascript, standards, accessibility

I am working on a large website (1600+ pages) that needs upgrading to pass standards compliance.  As a result, for every OnClick there has to be, say the Standards, an OnKeyPress handler, so that people not using a mouse can still access the content.

Some tags have an onclick javascript handler.  EG:

```
<a onclick="doSumat();">
```

Is the following cross browser, working javascript:

```
<a onclick="doSumat();" onkeypress="this.onclick();" >
```

Will it work reliably in all browsers and will the result be the same as a mouse click for someone using a screen reader?

Comment: When would an `onkeypress` event possibly fire when set on a `span` element?

Comment: well, ideally, your Javascript calls should be finished with a semicolon - ie `doSumat();` - but that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: I shall edit, my sloppy typing.

Comment: Some browsers will need this.click() and others will work only with this.onclick() however I'm not sure what exactly you ask here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, why not call `doSumat();` with both the onclick and onkeypress handlers?

If you need a `this` context, then you'll need to use `doSumat.call(this);`, but you can still place that in both handlers.

```
<a onclick="doSumat();" onkeypress="doSumat();">
```

With 1600 pages, I imagine you're trying to find something simple to append to every element with an `onclick` handler, but shouldn't be that much more complex to define rules to blindly copy everything from an `onclick` statement to an `onkeypress` expression.

Answer (score 6):

W3C - SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons.

While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button. The default action occurs when the user clicks the element with a mouse, but it also occurs when the user focuses the element and hits enter or space, and when the element is triggered via the accessibility API.

Source http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35

Comment: Actually, after loading the page and just hit the tab button to reach the input field when I start typing, the script will not get triggered unless I have an onkeypress handler.